# На службу встать или стать?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Завис над выражением "(в)стать на службу" ("(в)стать на защиту"). Как все-таки правильно: встать или стать?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На защиту встать, т.е. подняться, а на службу и не стают, и не встают, т.е. не поднимаются (если только не рано встал на службу в смысле поднялся с постели), а к службе можно приступить, на службу-определиться.

Answer (score 2):

Поступить на службу можно,определиться на службу,а какой контекст?

Comment: Вот именно! Контекст, господа! Что если автор вопроса под выражением "встать на службу" подразумевал "предложить свои услуги", т. е. "посвятить себя служению кому-нибудь или чему-либо"? "Встать на службу (у) интересов революции", например.

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно заступить на службу. Или это о дежурстве: заступил на дежурство?

Comment: Да,  заступают  на  дежурство.